# how can I match an day integer to AbbreviatedDayNames

Tags: c#, datetime

I have the following function that return a list of the short day names in a week.

```
        public static string[] GetDayNames(string cultureCode)
    {
        var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cultureCode);
        string[] names = culture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedDayNames;
        return names;
    }
```

I now need to match a specific dates day (integer value) to the correct AbbreviatedDayName, how can I do that?

Comment: Can you use the `System.DayOfWeek` enum?

Comment: Wait! do you expect a day integer to have a specific day of the week regardless of its month and year?

Comment: What does that integer value represent? Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is to convert the day into a date time and then to get the AbbreviatedDayName:

```
var ab = culture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedDayNames[((int)dt.DayOfWeek)];
```

or simply

```
var ab =  dt.ToString("ddd", culture);
```

Comment: I ended up doing this instead....        
 public static string GetLocalizedDayName(string cultureCode, DateTime dateValue)

        {

            return dateValue.ToString("ddd", new CultureInfo(cultureCode)).ToUpper();

        }

Answer (score 0):

> I now need to match a specific dates day (integer value) to the correct AbbreviatedDayName, how can I do that?

This is not possible. Not every 1<sup>st</sup> of every month is the same day of the week. You need to observe the entire date (year, month *and* day) before you can take a stab at what day of the week it is.